# Trying to import all google sheets files within a folder to a spreadsheet, all column headers are the same

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to be able to take all files from a a folder within drive and input the data into the spreadsheet. I am also creating a Menu Tab so I can just Run the script without going to editor. It would be great if I can create a way enter names of existing folder name without always going to the script in order to take out that extra step. This is the script I am using. I really need assistance with this.

```
function importTimesheets() {
 var spreadsheets = DriveApp.
   getFolderById("").
   getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);

 var data = [];
 while (spreadsheets.hasNext()) {
   var currentSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheets.next().getId());
   data = data.concat(currentSpreadsheet   
                        .getSheetByName('Timesheet')
                      .getRange("A3:L10")
                        .getValues()
                          );
 }

 SpreadsheetApp.
   getActiveSheet().
   getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).
   setValues(data);
}


function onOpen() {
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 ui.createMenu('Generate Timesheets')
     .addItem('Generate', 'importTimesheets')
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between yout title of `Trying to import all google sheets files within a folder to a spreadsheet, all column headers are the same` and `It would be great if I can create a way enter names of existing folder name without always going to the script in order to take out that extra step.` in your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: No apologize need. Every day timesheets are created and they all have different  file names but they all have the same format. I need to take all the data from all these files and input them into one weekly spreadsheet.

Comment: I will then use this method to generate weekly timesheets with ease. Due to covid the amount of data is small; but realistically, ill be dealing with well over 20 timesheets a day, well 2000 entries a week.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are trying to find a solution for this line of code, whereby you currently have to enter the Id manually.

```
   DriveApp.getFolderById("")
```

My suggestions would be to prompt the user for the folder Id, because prompting for the folder name may cause errors if more than one folder has the same name. My suggestion is implemented as follows:

```
const folderId = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Please enter the Folder Id").getResponseText()
const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId)
```

You could also use the Google File/Folder picker, as [described here](https://www.pbainbridge.co.uk/2020/03/google-drive-picker-for-folder-id.html) to search and select the folder.

Comment: oh no I just left that blank for confidential reasonings.. my problem was with .get range, it came up as an error. Although, I will most definitely try your code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var level=0;
function getFnF(folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder()) {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  const files=folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    let file=files.next();
    let firg=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1,level + 1);
    firg.setValue(Utilities.formatString('File: %s', file.getName()));//need editing
  }
  const subfolders=folder.getFolders() 
  while(subfolders.hasNext()) {
    let subfolder=subfolders.next();
    let forg=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1,level + 1);
    forg.setValue(Utilities.formatString('Fldr: %s', subfolder.getName()));//needs editing
    level++;
    getFnF(subfolder);
  }
  level--;
}

function runThisFirst() {
  let r = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Folder id','Enter Folder Id',SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(r.getResponseText())
  getFnF(folder);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Cooper, I think this code will work  but I'm assuming that Line 9 will get the files with certain name. They all have different names and I need it to grab everything from the folder.

Comment: files is an iterator for files of MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS